# Azure Application Insight Work items authorization error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-application-insights, workitem

My purpose is to create bug in Azure DevOps directly from Azure Application Insight, I am doing to attach the work item (bug) feature available in Azure Application Insight but on clicking Authorize button it give me following error

> Authorization token provided through OAuth does not have access to read/write work items for requested uri/project collection/project

for reference please find the below image. [image]

**Updates:**
I didnt understand what you meant by private browser, and I have full admin access over Azure Portal.

basically I have the https://dev.azure.com/HealthTechnologies/ReportItNow link in which

https://dev.azure.com  is the devop url

HealthTechnologies is the organization

ReportItNow is the Project

so in Azure insight workitem section, URL I am putting https://dev.azure.com/HealthTechnologies/ and in project I am putting ReportItNow,  I dont know what i am doing wrong.

> **Still waiting for this glitch to solve.**
>
> Oky let me make it more simple, if I want to automatically create bug in Azure DevOps when ever any new exception came in to the Azure
>   Application Insight  How I can get this into real practical.

Comment: Try doing that in a **private** browser window to avoid effects from other accounts. And if that still persists, check if [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/406512/view.html) helps. You may need to use old format for this.

Comment: What's the result if you enter URL `https://HealthTechnologies.visualstudio.com`, it's old format of `https://dev.azure.com`. It looks one issue with Azure Application Insight but I can't reproduce it in my side, see if [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/360428/unable-to-link-appinsights-with-azure-devops.html) makes some help.  And the `private window` I mean edge's `New InPrivate Window` and Chrome's new incognito window. It's private mode of browser.

Comment: I have tried  https://HealthTechnologies.visualstudio.com in URL field and in chrome incognito mode but same result :(

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I have tired your suggestion but same result, please guild where is the mistake?

Comment: Any1 know from where I am doing mistake or is this the glitch from azure

Comment: Apart from the admin permission in Azure portal, do you have necessary permissions in Azure Devops Collection and Project? Please also make sure you have the permission to create work Item directly in Azure Devops Web Portal.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT  I have full access on Azure DevOps along with the Azure Portal, Plus I am the owner of the organization and able to create any thing on dev.azure.portal plus work item, I mean I have the full access on both portals.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this when I took a detailed look at the error message url. It's saying that the missing authorization is for https://uri/Project Collection/Project. Based on that, I changed my url from https://dev.azure.com/organization to https://dev.azure.com/ and it worked,

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Let me try this and I'll update here: